# localhost:8080 always redirect to localhost:3000

Tags: wordpress, macos, docker, localhost, browser-sync

I have a **WordPress development environment with Docker**. Is so simple, only a docker compose with Wordpress and MySQL.

This is my docker-compose file. All works perfect, and at first I can see my WordPress in **localhost:8080**

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /Users/ivan/Developer/theme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/theme
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

I also use **Browser Sync** with Gulp to live reload the site. I config in Browser Sync settings a **proxy** and then I can see my WordPress in **localhost:3000** and *my_local_ip*:3000 with live reload.

```
browsersync: {
    browser: 'google chrome',
    proxy: "localhost:8080",
},
```

The problem is that I made some changes in WordPress url settings (And then I restored it) but now the redirections works bad.

- If I try to go to localhost:8080 or *my_local_ip*:3000 the browser always redirect to localhost:3000 and show a "too many redirects" error. (**even with BrowserSync and Docker shutdown**).
- With Docker and BrowserSync running, *my_local_ip*:3000/wp-admin and localhost:3000/wp-admin **works perfectly**, but I can't see my blog. **localhost:3000 always shows the error**.

I already tried to **clear the browsers cache**, but not solve it. I don't now if is an error or a bad configuration of **Docker**, **BrowserSync** or **MacOS** (High Sierra is my OS)

Comment: I think the problem is on your Wordpress configuration. If it was working and after you changed some configuration started to loop redirect, for sure it's Wordpress. I'm not an expert on Wordpress, but I know Wordpress saves some hardcoded URL's on the database. Take a look and see if every URL is properly configured. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but is strange that the redirect works even with Docker containers (WordPress and MySQL) down.

Comment: Did you try "Private mode" ?

Comment: Yes, but not solve it

Comment: Clearing cache often doesn't clear redirects ( yeah, it's pain ). you can run in console `fetch('http://localhost:{port}', {method: 'post'}).then(() => {})` which should clear the cache.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue just now, and solved it. So here are my findings.

WordPress uses the `Host` header to determine where the traffic comes from and redirects it based on the configurations set.

Since you're using BrowserSync as proxy, BrowserSync sends a request to `localhost:8080` with the `Host` header value as `localhost:8080` instead of where you are sending your request from.

So first thing to do is have BrowserSync use the right host. We can grab the host from the original request like this

```
proxy: {
    target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    proxyReq: [
        function(proxyReq, req, res) {
                proxyReq.setHeader('Host', req.headers.host);
        }
    ]
},
```

And next make sure that `WordPress Address (URL)` and
`Site Address (URL)` url are set correctly in `WP-Admin -> Settings -> General`

`[host:port]/wp-admin/options-general.php`

That should do it. Worked for me, at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
proxyReq: [
    function(proxyReq, req, res) {
            proxyReq.setHeader('Host', req.headers.host);
    }
]
```

If you are using WordPress with Browsersync, this will do it. Thank you [@software-person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11702000/software-person)

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for change Browsersync options:

```
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(); // npm install browser-sync --save-dev

const
// source and build folders
dir = {
  watch: 'source-theme/',
  build: 'build-theme/'
},

// Browsersync options:
const syncOpts = {
  port: 3000, 
  proxy: 'http://mywebsite.ss',
  files: dir.watch + '**/*',
  open: true,
  notify: false,
  ghostMode: false,
  ui: {
    port: 8001, //default port 8080
    weinre: {
        port: 8002 //default weinre port 9090
    }
  },
};

// browser-sync task
gulp.task('browserSync', () => {
  browserSync.init(syncOpts);
});
```

for more info https://browsersync.io/docs/options